# R regex remove apostrophes NOT between letters

Tags: regex, r

I'm able to remove all punctuation from a string while keeping apostrophes, but I'm now stuck on how to remove any apostrophes that are not between two letters.

```
str1 <- "I don't know 'how' to remove these ' things"
```

Should look like this:

```
"I don't know how to remove these things"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a regex approach:

```
str1 <- "I don't know 'how' to remove these ' things"
gsub("\\s*'\\B|\\B'\\s*", "", str1)
```

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Di2nYj) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE8nW5/1).

The regex matches:

- `\\s*'\\B` - 0+ whitespaces, `'` and a non-word boundary
- `|`  - or
- `\\B'\\s*` - a non-word boundary, `'` and 0+ whitespaces

If you do not need to care about the extra whitespace that can remain after removing standalone `'`, you can use a PCRE regex like

```
\b'\b(*SKIP)(*F)|'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE8nW5/2)

**Explanation**:

- `\b'\b` - match a `'` in-between word characters
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - and omit the match
- `|` - or match...
- `'` - an apostrophe in another context.

See an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/q9h7RW):

```
gsub("\\b'\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|'", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
```

**To account for apostrophes in-between Unicode letters**, add `(*UTF)(*UCP)` flags at the start of the pattern and use a `perl=TRUE` argument:

```
gsub("(*UTF)(*UCP)\\s*'\\B|\\B'\\s*", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

Or

```
gsub("(*UTF)(*UCP)\\b'\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|'", "", str1, perl=TRUE) 
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/oGIvhA)

Comment: @Phillip can you explain for future users why this is perfect?  I suspect it's the removal of added white space that you forgot to describe in your post but without that understanding it's just speculation.

Comment: I apologize, I tried to edit my comment but it was too late.  I selected this answer since it only required one line of code and it worked when I tried it, where as @lmo's answer didn't at first but did after he corrected it.

Comment: See my latest edit to see the difference between my approach and the one suggested by lmo.

Answer (score 4):

This method using `gsub` work:

```
gsub("(([^A-Za-z])'|'([^A-Za-z]))", "\\2 ", str1)

"I don't know  how to remove these   things"
```

It would require a second round to remove extra spaces. So

```
gsub("  +", " ", gsub("(([^A-Za-z])'|'([^A-Za-z]))", "\\2 ", str1))
```

- [^A-Za-z] says all non-alphabetical characters
- | is an or statement
- () capture matched sub-expressions
- \\2 is called a back reference and returns the second captured sub-expressions

Comment: Similar to mine but using the negation & no need for the perl.  Clever.

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks. I have the disadvantage of learning regex through the limited Stata regex pallet. No fancy perl tools available. Gradually growing the vocabulary.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using lookarounds in base:

```
gsub("(?<![a-zA-Z])(')|(')(?![a-zA-Z])", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "I don't know how to remove these  things"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: `gsub("([a-zA-Z]'[a-zA-Z])|'", "\\1", str1)` =)